# Get calendar events from google business account

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

At this moment I can get events from a calendar using a Gmail account without any inconvenience. For this I use a `AccountChooser` and `GoogleAccountCredential` to obtain the information and permissions necessary to synchronize correctly in an android application. But when I try to use a google business account (xxxxx@business.com), it asks me to install `GoogleDevicePolicy App` and unless I install and configure this app, it does not allow me to synchronize the calendar of this account and by conclusion I can not get the events of this calendar . How can I get events from this calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow Google's instruction and do what it's asking you to do, i.e., install the GoogleDevPolicy App. This is  a [security measure](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/190930?hl=en) since your email is non-Gmail.

> The Google Apps Device Policy app enforces security policies on your
>   Android device to protect it and make it more secure.
>
> Some organizations require their users to install the Google Apps
>   Device Policy app on their device. Failure to install the app may
>   block your mail, calendar, and contacts from syncing with your device.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this info. Have a nice day!